# How refer to global variable in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I would like to add numbers from input in function to `candidate_Adam` variable. How to do this?

```
candidate_Adam = 0
candidate_Anna = 0
candidate_Kamil = 0

def elektor1():
    while True:
        print('Wskaż w skali od 1 do 3 (gdzie 3 oznacza najbardziej przypadł mi do gustu) jak mocno przypadł Ci do gustu : ')
        vote1_1 = input('kandydat nr 1 - Adam Nowak: ')
        vote1_2 = input('kandydat nr 2 - Anna Woda: ')
        vote1_3 = input('kandydat nr 3 - Kamil Pol: ')
        vote1_1, vote1_2, vote1_3 = int(vote1_1), int(vote1_2), int(vote1_3)

        if (vote1_1 == vote1_2) or (vote1_2 == vote1_3) or (vote1_3 == vote1_1):
            print('Nie można dopasowac takich samych preferencji do kilku kandydatów!')
            continue
        return  vote1_1 , vote1_2 , vote1_3
```

Comment: You can still use global variables in a function. That's the reason they're called global variables. Have you even tried to do what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to add do:  candidate_Adam += vote1_1 and that was unresolved reference error

Comment: Then use the global keyword and the variable at the beginning of the function

Comment: Ok thx, but still i have problem, because i want to use candidate_Adam in another function but with added value. 
I have 10 function, all looks the same but got different variables from input and i need to add all variables results to candidate_Adam variable

Comment: edit your original question, and add your latest question.
and if you got your answer please upvote